# Trying to parse XML string into c# object with no success

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I'm trying to Deserialize some XML string into an object. but always got the next error:

> There is an error in XML document (1, 2). <VehicleMediaLinksRsp
> xmlns='http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0'> was not
> expected.

I also tried to remove `xmlns:vehicle=\"http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0\"` from the xml
but then I get: 'vehicle' is an undeclared prefix. Line 1, position 2.

the object is:

```
namespace VehicleMedia
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "SupplierRate", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0")]
    public class SupplierRate
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "RateForPeriod")]
        public string RateForPeriod { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ExtraMileageCharge")]
        public string ExtraMileageCharge { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "VehicleRate", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0")]
    public class VehicleRate
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SupplierRate", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0")]
        public SupplierRate SupplierRate { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "RatePeriod")]
        public string RatePeriod { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Vehicle", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0")]
    public class Vehicle
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "VehicleRate", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0")]
        public VehicleRate VehicleRate { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "VendorCode")]
        public string VendorCode { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "AirConditioning")]
        public string AirConditioning { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TransmissionType")]
        public string TransmissionType { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "VehicleClass")]
        public string VehicleClass { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "DoorCount")]
        public string DoorCount { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "AcrissVehicleCode")]
        public string AcrissVehicleCode { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "MediaItem", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v48_0")]
    public class MediaItem
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "sizeCode")]
        public string SizeCode { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "VehicleWithMediaItems", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0")]
    public class VehicleWithMediaItems
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Vehicle", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0")]
        public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "MediaItem", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v48_0")]
        public MediaItem MediaItem { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "VehicleMediaLinksRsp", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0")]
    public class VehicleMediaLinksRsp
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "VehicleWithMediaItems", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0")]
        public List<VehicleWithMediaItems> VehicleWithMediaItems { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TransactionId")]
        public string TransactionId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ResponseTime")]
        public string ResponseTime { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "vehicle", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Vehicle { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "common_v48_0", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Common_v48_0 { get; set; }
    }

}
```

and the xml string for example is:

```xml
<vehicle:VehicleMediaLinksRsp xmlns:vehicle="http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0" xmlns:common_v48_0="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v48_0" TransactionId="29EAAF810A07571D5ADA0638F657E2D2" ResponseTime="173">
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZE" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Economy" Category="Car" DoorCount="TwoToThreeDoors" AcrissVehicleCode="EBMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="http://cdn.travelport.com/cmhertz/ZE_general_large_191388.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZE" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Economy" Category="Car" DoorCount="FourToFiveDoors" AcrissVehicleCode="EDMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="http://cdn.travelport.com/cmhertz/ZE_general_large_191418.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZE" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Compact" Category="Car" DoorCount="FourToFiveDoors" AcrissVehicleCode="CDMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="http://cdn.travelport.com/cmhertz/ZE_general_large_190022.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZE" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Automatic" VehicleClass="Compact" Category="Car" DoorCount="FourToFiveDoors" AcrissVehicleCode="CDAR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="http://cdn.travelport.com/cmhertz/ZE_general_large_190054.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZE" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Automatic" VehicleClass="Intermediate" Category="Car" DoorCount="FourToFiveDoors" AcrissVehicleCode="IDAR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="http://cdn.travelport.com/cmhertz/ZE_general_large_190092.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZE" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Standard" Category="Van" AcrissVehicleCode="SVMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmhertz/ZE_general_large_180977.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZE" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Automatic" VehicleClass="Fullsize" Category="Van" AcrissVehicleCode="FVAR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="http://cdn.travelport.com/cmhertz/ZE_general_large_187803.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZE" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Premium" Category="Van" AcrissVehicleCode="PVMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="http://cdn.travelport.com/cmhertz/ZE_general_large_187547.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZE" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Compact" Category="StationWagon" AcrissVehicleCode="CWMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="http://cdn.travelport.com/cmhertz/ZE_general_large_191256.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZE" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Intermediate" Category="Monospace" AcrissVehicleCode="IMMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="http://cdn.travelport.com/cmhertz/ZE_general_large_190846.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZE" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Mini" Category="Special" AcrissVehicleCode="MXMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="http://cdn.travelport.com/cmhertz/ZE_general_large_188986.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZE" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Standard" Category="Special" AcrissVehicleCode="SXMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="http://cdn.travelport.com/cmhertz/ZE_general_large_190366.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZL" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Mini" Category="Car" DoorCount="FourToFiveDoors" AcrissVehicleCode="MDMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmnational/ZL_general_large_23221.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZL" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Economy" Category="Car" DoorCount="FourToFiveDoors" AcrissVehicleCode="EDMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmnational/ZL_general_large_23213.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZL" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Compact" Category="Car" DoorCount="FourToFiveDoors" AcrissVehicleCode="CDMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmnational/ZL_general_large_23210.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZL" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Automatic" VehicleClass="Intermediate" Category="Car" DoorCount="FourToFiveDoors" AcrissVehicleCode="IDAR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmnational/ZL_general_large_23218.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZL" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Fullsize" Category="Van" AcrissVehicleCode="FVMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmnational/ZL_general_large_23216.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZL" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Standard" Category="StationWagon" AcrissVehicleCode="SWMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmnational/ZL_general_large_23225.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZL" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Automatic" VehicleClass="Standard" Category="StationWagon" AcrissVehicleCode="SWAR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmnational/ZL_general_large_23224.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ZL" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Automatic" VehicleClass="Luxury" Category="StationWagon" AcrissVehicleCode="LWAR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmnational/ZL_general_large_23220.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="AL" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Mini" Category="Car" DoorCount="FourToFiveDoors" AcrissVehicleCode="MDMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmalamo/AL_general_large_6844.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="AL" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Economy" Category="Car" DoorCount="FourToFiveDoors" AcrissVehicleCode="EDMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmalamo/AL_general_large_6831.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="AL" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Compact" Category="Car" DoorCount="FourToFiveDoors" AcrissVehicleCode="CDMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmalamo/AL_general_large_6827.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="AL" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Automatic" VehicleClass="Intermediate" Category="Car" DoorCount="FourToFiveDoors" AcrissVehicleCode="IDAR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmalamo/AL_general_large_6838.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="AL" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Fullsize" Category="Van" AcrissVehicleCode="FVMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmalamo/AL_general_large_6835.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="AL" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Standard" Category="StationWagon" AcrissVehicleCode="SWMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmalamo/AL_general_large_6849.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="AL" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Automatic" VehicleClass="Standard" Category="StationWagon" AcrissVehicleCode="SWAR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmalamo/AL_general_large_6848.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="AL" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Automatic" VehicleClass="Luxury" Category="StationWagon" AcrissVehicleCode="LWAR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmalamo/AL_general_large_6843.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ET" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Mini" Category="Car" DoorCount="FourToFiveDoors" AcrissVehicleCode="MDMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmenterprise/ET_general_large_13568.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ET" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Economy" Category="Car" DoorCount="FourToFiveDoors" AcrissVehicleCode="EDMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmenterprise/ET_general_large_13561.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ET" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Compact" Category="Car" DoorCount="FourToFiveDoors" AcrissVehicleCode="CDMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmenterprise/ET_general_large_13558.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ET" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Automatic" VehicleClass="Intermediate" Category="Car" DoorCount="FourToFiveDoors" AcrissVehicleCode="IDAR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmenterprise/ET_general_large_13565.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ET" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Fullsize" Category="Van" AcrissVehicleCode="FVMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmenterprise/ET_general_large_13564.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ET" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Manual" VehicleClass="Standard" Category="StationWagon" AcrissVehicleCode="SWMR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmenterprise/ET_general_large_13572.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ET" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Automatic" VehicleClass="Standard" Category="StationWagon" AcrissVehicleCode="SWAR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmenterprise/ET_general_large_13571.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
   <vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
      <vehicle:Vehicle VendorCode="ET" AirConditioning="true" TransmissionType="Automatic" VehicleClass="Luxury" Category="StationWagon" AcrissVehicleCode="LWAR">
         <vehicle:VehicleRate RatePeriod="Other">
            <vehicle:SupplierRate RateForPeriod="USD0.00" ExtraMileageCharge="USD0.00" />
         </vehicle:VehicleRate>
      </vehicle:Vehicle>
      <common_v48_0:MediaItem url="https://cdn.travelport.com/cmenterprise/ET_general_large_13567.jpg" sizeCode="S" />
   </vehicle:VehicleWithMediaItems>
</vehicle:VehicleMediaLinksRsp>
```

so why do i get this error?
thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would really help if you could provide a [mcve] for this, with a well-formatted but *short* XML document instead of a giant document that's all on a single line. I suspect that just a root element with one child element, with classes to match, would be enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Please pay attention to formatting. The error that explains what's wrong was mangled and the XML text is one reaaaaaaaally long and unreadable line. You only need the first XML element to reproduce such an error, none of the contents.

Comment: Are you sure? The error message does not fit to the XML. Can you please show the code where you try to deserialize the XML?

Comment: XmlSerializer serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(VehicleMedia.VehicleMediaLinksRsp));
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {

                VehicleMedia.VehicleMediaLinksRsp Vmedia = (VehicleMedia.VehicleMediaLinksRsp)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
            }

Comment: Did you know that you can [edit] your question? It is better to add additional information to your question instead of hiding it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works.   Tested below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication166
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(file);
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(VehicleMediaLinksRsp));
            VehicleMediaLinksRsp vehicleMediaLinksRsp = (VehicleMediaLinksRsp)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "SupplierRate", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0")]
    public class SupplierRate
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "RateForPeriod")]
        public string RateForPeriod { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ExtraMileageCharge")]
        public string ExtraMileageCharge { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "VehicleRate", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0")]
    public class VehicleRate
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SupplierRate", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0")]
        public SupplierRate SupplierRate { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "RatePeriod")]
        public string RatePeriod { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Vehicle", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0")]
    public class Vehicle
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "VehicleRate", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0")]
        public VehicleRate VehicleRate { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "VendorCode")]
        public string VendorCode { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "AirConditioning")]
        public string AirConditioning { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TransmissionType")]
        public string TransmissionType { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "VehicleClass")]
        public string VehicleClass { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "DoorCount")]
        public string DoorCount { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "AcrissVehicleCode")]
        public string AcrissVehicleCode { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "MediaItem", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v48_0")]
    public class MediaItem
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "sizeCode")]
        public string SizeCode { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "VehicleWithMediaItems", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0")]
    public class VehicleWithMediaItems
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Vehicle", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0")]
        public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "MediaItem", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v48_0")]
        public MediaItem MediaItem { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "VehicleMediaLinksRsp", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0")]
    public class VehicleMediaLinksRsp
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "VehicleWithMediaItems", Namespace = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/vehicle_v48_0")]
        public List<VehicleWithMediaItems> VehicleWithMediaItems { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TransactionId")]
        public string TransactionId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ResponseTime")]
        public string ResponseTime { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "vehicle", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Vehicle { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "common_v48_0", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Common_v48_0 { get; set; }
    }

 
}
```